# How to store variable cell data to editbox gui

Tags: matlab, user-interface

I want to store data from cell to my editbox in gui, but data didnt show up on editbox

```
r=controlling(NR);
if ~isempty(r) 
    I={Iprops.Image}; 
    noPlate=[];
    for v=1:length(r)
        N=I{1,r(v)};
        letter=readLetter(N);
        while letter=='O' || letter=='0'
        letter='O';              
        else                         
        letter='0';             
        end                         
        break;                      
        end
    noPlate=[noPlate letter];
    a = cellstr(noPlate)
    set(handles.edit1,'String',a)


function edit1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)

get(hObject,'String');
handles.edit1 = edit1;
guidata(hObject,handles)
```

[gui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xoRlW.jpg)

I practice recognize numberplate using template matching, noPlate data is characters and numbers. there's no error showing but data didnt showup . How to fix this ? thanks

Comment: Can you provide some values for `noPlate` etc. so we can actually run this? Also a screenshot of what you're seeing could help

Comment: thanks for reply sir! , i've updated the post.

Comment: That doesn't run as it's invalid syntax. Please post a [mcve]

Comment: do you get any error or warning messages? what's the content of` `a` before you set the String of `edit1`?

Comment: @Suever There are so many line codes sir cz the program has divided into 5 (dot)m files. sorry if you assume the data is in [ ] , it would be help if i use syntax cell2str and store to my edit box ? thanks b4 .

Comment: @bushmills there's no massages warning sir, i assume the data is in [ ] , and i read refference , cz i use syntax on my editbox like this get(hObject,'String'); , it would be help if i use syntax cell2str , but it wasn't. content is alphabets and numbers sir